# Is it possible to enable "Focus follows Scrolling"?

Tags: mouse, window-manager, ui, macos

I tried out Focus follows mouse and found too many occasions when it really annoys me. Thinking about the cases when I would need focus follows mouse, I realized that it's only necessary when I'm scrolling in a non-active window.

So: Is there the possibility of having the focus switch to a window in that I scroll? Either via some setting or external application?

Answer (score 1):

I find that many applications already behave this way.  At least with a trackpad.

If I am working in this window, responding to your comment, and I hover over another Safari window, OR over my iTunes window, I can scroll without clicking on the other window.

My computer is *not* set to Focus follows mouse.

It may well be that some applications do not support this...

Do you have a specific set of apps in mind?

Comment: Please re-read my question: Is there the possibility of having the *focus switch to a window in that I scroll*? I do want to have the focus changed if I scroll in some other window.

Comment: Sorry about that...  I see what you are looking for now.   I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: I'm just looking into doing that programatically now and have posted an appropriate question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316105/system-wide-recognition-of-scroll-events-on-mac-osx-and-setting-focus-to-a-differ